# Finding a Sequence Decreasing faster than a countable collection of sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, convergence-divergence

For each $n\in \mathbb N$, let $\alpha_m^{(n)}$ be a sequence in $m$ which strictly decreasing to $0$. Can we find a sequence $\alpha_m$ which also decreases strictly to $0$, such that $\alpha_m=O_n(\alpha_m^{(n)})$ for all $n$? Note the implied constant here may depend on $n$.

For example, if $\alpha_m^{(n)}=m^{-1/n}$, then we can take $\alpha_m=2^{-m}$. But I would like to know if this result holds in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about $\alpha_m:=\min\{\alpha_m^{(n)}:1\leq n\leq m\}$?

Comment: Thanks! Your answer solved my problem perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

What if $\alpha^{(n)}_m = \frac{1}{n+m}$. Then each $\alpha_m$ would have to be 0.

Comment: Nope. I think $\alpha_m$ can be taken to be $m^{-2}$.

Comment: @DongLi it cannot though, $\alpha_m$ has to be $O(\alpha^{(n)}_m)$ for all $n$. This is impossible if the $\alpha^{(n)}_m$s go to 0 with fixed $m$ and $n$.

Comment: But the constant in the big $O$ notation could depend on each $n$.